How to subtract a dataframe with repeating sample IDs by a ref data set
I have the following reference dataframe (ref_df) and a dataframe_1 (df1)
ref_df
| Sample_Name | Value |
| --------    | -------- |
| CTRL        | 18.17    |
| E-1         | 19.06    |
| FIB         | 17.78    |
| 10nM Benz   | 17.89    |

df1 
| Sample_Name | Value |
| --------    | -------- |
| CTRL        | 27.49    |
| E-1         | 28.89    |
| FIB         | 24.81    |
| 10nM Benz   | 24.24    |
| CTRL        | 27.36    |
| E-1         | 28.87    |
| FIB         | 24.66    |
| 10nM Benz   | 24.32    |```

I would like to take make the following happen: df1 - ref_df to obtain the df_result dataframe. 
Notice how each Sample id is subtracted by it corresponding id in the ref_df. 
The problem here seems to be the difference in size of the dfs and making sure 
each value is subtracted by the correct corresponding ref_df ID.


``` df_result 
| Sample_Name | Value |
| --------    | -------- |
| CTRL        | 9.32    |
| E-1         | 9.83    |
| FIB         | 7.03    |
| 10nM Benz   | 6.35    |
| CTRL        | 9.19    |
| E-1         | 9.81    |
| FIB         | 6.88    |
| 10nM Benz   | 6.43    | 

How do I subtract the ref_df from df1 while making sure the correct things get subtracted according to Sample_name. On top of that, I'm unsure how to address the mismatch in the number of values (since ref_df has 4 values and df1 has 8). I'd like to keep the duplicate values as they are replicates and will need them for additional arithmetic later on.
I tried duplicating the ref_df to account for the mismatch in shape between the two dataframes, however that results in subtracting taking place without taking into account Sample_Name

Try:
df_result = (
    df1.set_index("Sample_Name")["Value"] - ref_df.set_index("Sample_Name")["Value"]
).reset_index()

Prints:
  Sample_Name  Value
0   10nM Benz   6.35
1   10nM Benz   6.43
2        CTRL   9.32
3        CTRL   9.19
4         E-1   9.83
5         E-1   9.81
6         FIB   7.03
7         FIB   6.88


OR: Put result into df1:
df1["Result"] = df1["Value"] - df1["Sample_Name"].map(
    ref_df.set_index("Sample_Name")["Value"]
)
print(df1)

Prints:
  Sample_Name  Value  Result
0        CTRL  27.49    9.32
1         E-1  28.89    9.83
2         FIB  24.81    7.03
3   10nM Benz  24.24    6.35
4        CTRL  27.36    9.19
5         E-1  28.87    9.81
6         FIB  24.66    6.88
7   10nM Benz  24.32    6.43


Thank you! I like the second approach of adding it to df1 . However, I'm getting a 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' which I assume is because because the index (or in this case the Sample_Name identifies are not the same?

@cadillac_carlito Does ref_df have duplicates in Sample_Name? I suggest to drop them with .drop_duplicates()

ref_df does not have duplicates in Sample_Name. However df1 does. I can't get rid of the duplicates in Sample_Name for df1 because they represent a second trial of data that will be used for averaging later on. The averaging cannot be done at this step. It's almost as if I'd like to subtract rows 0-3 from ref_df and 4-7 from ref_df and, as you mentioned, add them to df1 as a separate column.

Sorry youre right my ref_df did have duplicates! This worked beautifully, thank you! I've been stuck on this for quite some time and you eat it for lunch, you're a god. @Andrej Kesely
